# Extending default partition without losing data

Tags: debian, partition

I have a `VPS` with only a `SSH` access. This is hosted on [OVH](https://www.ovh.com).

The `VPS` is a Debian 9 (stretch). (I don't have `LVM` partition)

The size limit was a problem so I ordered an additional disk of 100G.

The default size of the disk was 25G and I already installed a few things on it and don't want to reconfigure everything.

Result of `lsblk`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   25G  0 disk
└─sda1   8:1    0   25G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0  100G  0 disk
```

I want to extend the `/var` which is in the volume `/dev/sda1`. This volume is the bootable one and is currently in use.

What is recommended in my use case?

Comment: Unless I am not seeing something, you are not dealing with unallocated space on a disk where your `sda1` partition could be "extended". The `sdb` listed is another storage disk alltogether. While it is possible to span a 'volume' across two storage devices, but it is a bit crazy. It becomes a "one-for-all, all-for-one" situation, such that if one of the drives fails, the whole volume goes up in smoke, and data recovery rates will vary between zero, and not enough for this to be a good idea. What you want to do is set-up a new mount point for `/var` .

Answer (score 1):

What I believe you are looking is changing the mount point of `/var` to a new partition on disk `sdb`,  while preserving all of the data in that folder. Since this is a running server, I will be as descriptive as I can, especially with respect to commands used and their flags.

Also, I would highly recommend putting your server in some administrative/stand-by/offline (aside from the current admin connection) mode, so there is no risk to data integrity (close any db connections and other unnecessary sockets at the very least)

---

### Partition your new `/dev/sdb` disk

First, we need to setup `sdb` by creating a partition. Here I am going to assume `/var` is the one that is and will continue growing on your server, and accordingly I am going to dedicate virtually the full capacity of `sdb` to it (you can obviously adjust the size of the new partition as required for your own server, and leave unallocated space for future use if so desired).

Use `parted` to create a partion table on `sdb`

```bsh
$ sudo parted /dev/sdb mklabel gpt
```

Next create a primary partition on the disk, aligning on cylinder, with `ext4` format. The `1024MB` corresponds to the free space in the beginning of the disk, which is way more than enough for writing any MBR (but will allow for some potential rescue mode, if ever needed). The `100%` at the end means extend to the end of available space.

```bsh
$ sudo parted -a cylinder /dev/sdb mkpart primary ext4 1024MB 100%
```

Check if everything was created correctly (this sample output was created on the fly, but yours should show two disks, with the new partition created and visible where /dev/sdb gets listed)

```bsh
$ sudo parted -l



Model: [MODEL]
Disk /dev/sda: 25GB
Sector size (logical/physical): [*/*]
Partition Table: [mklabel]
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  25GB  25GB  primary      ext4         lba

Model: [MODEL]
Disk /dev/sdb: 100GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049MB  100GB  100GB  primary      ext4
```

If everything looks good partion-wise you can move on.

---

### Sync the data from `/var`to `sdb1` .

1. What needs to be done

   - make a new `/mnt` folder for `sdb1` and mount it there
   - copy data from `/var/*`to `sdb1`
   - check for consistency with `diff`
   - check `diff_var.log` for inconsistency info

First, we need to mount our new `sdb1` partition. Your system will likely have `/mnt` present already, but if not the `-p` flag in the first command will take care of it.

```bsh
$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt/sdb1
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
```

2. Next, we `rsync` our `/var/*` data to it, and check for data consistency.

The `-a` flag is a shortcut of multiple other `rsync` flags combined together ( with the exception of the hard links `-H` flag), and means `rsync` everything there, recursively. The `-v` flag will show you a list of the files as they are being copied. The folder `var` will be created on `/dev/sdb1`

```bsh
$ sudo rsync -av /var/* /mnt/sdb1
```

3. Once that is done, check for consistency between the two folders, on two different partitions with `diff` with the `-r` recursive flag . This will be another time-consuming operatio. Also, redirecting the output to a log file is highly advisable.

```bsh
$ sudo diff -r /var /mnt/sdb1 > ~/diff_var.log
```

If you check diff_var.log, will likely have some lines resembling the following:

```bsh
# socket - no point in copying directly
File /var/*/[socket] is a socket while file /mnt/sdb1/var/*/[socket] is a socket

# Self-explanatory, log file update between `diff` and `rsync`*
diff -r /var/log/* /mnt/sdb1/var/log/* differs
199369d199368
< Dec 12 13:05:01 * * *

# Broken symlink
diff: /var/*/*/ABC No such file or directory
diff: /mnt/sdb1/var/*/*/ABC No such file or directory
```

4. Unmount `sdb1` partition.

```bsh
$ sudo umount /mnt/sdb1
```

---

### Add the new entry to `/etc/fstab`

1. Backup your current `/etc/fstab`

```bsh
$ sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.back
```

2. This is one is a test, and I highly recommended going through the steps It involves:

   - getting your `/dev/sdb1` UUID , and reformatting in `/etc/fstab` format
   - checking if the new partition mounts correctly from a new `/etc/fstab` entry

```bsh
###Getting your UUID
$ sudo blkid -s UUID /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: UUID="94c3f14d-508d-4621-9000-cbd4fc4c7445"

# var that holds a properly formatted line for /etc/fstab
$ my_uuid_sdb1=$(blkid -s UUID /dev/sdb1 | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d '"') 

# echo it to make sure
$ echo $my_uuid_sdb1
UUID=94c3f14d-508d-4621-9000-cbd4fc4c7445
```

If the ouput of the above command looks good on your system, you can append it to `/etc/fstab` as follows.

```bsh
$ sudo echo "$my_uuid_sdb1 /mnt/sdb1 ext4 defaults 0 2" >> /etc/fstab
```

Just to make sure, `diff` the two `fstab` files.

```bsh
# diff /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.back should only report one new line
$ sudo diff /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.back
33a34
< UUID=94c3f14d-508d-4621-9000-cbd4fc4c7445 /mnt/sdb1 ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Test it with `mount -a` and your new partition should report as successfully mounted like so:

```bsh
$ sudo mount -av
/                        : ignored
/mnt/sdb1                : successfully mounted

#checking with ls to see if we can see /var folder structure 
$ sudo ls /mnt/sdb1
*******  cache  local  log  *****   run    *****   tmp       
backups  lib    lock   mail  opt    spool  www     ***
```

Unmount it again

```bsh
$ sudo umount /mnt/sdb1
```

---

### Backup current `/var` to `/var.back` and change the mount-point of `/dev/sdb1` to `/var`

```bsh
$ sudo mv /var /var.back

### remake /var dir in /
$ sudo mkdir /var
```

Edit `/etc/fstab` again, and ensure the line was propely changed (better yet re-check whole /etc/fstab).

```bsh
# Use a visual editor and change /mnt/sdb1 to /var in /etc/fstab
# or use awk with gsub and inplace, directly from terminal  
$ sudo awk -i inplace  '/mnt\sdb1/gsub(/mnt\/sdb1/,"var")' /etc/fstab

$ sudo grep var /etc/fstab 
UUID=94c3f14d-508d-4621-9000-cbd4fc4c7445 /var ext4 defaults 0 2
```

First run `mount -av` and check the mount-point list with `df` for `sdb1` mounted on `/var`

```bsh
$ sudo mount -av 

$ sudo df -h /var
Filesystem      Size   Used   Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       50.7G  6.9G  1.4G   14% /var
```

If it all looks good, reboot your server.